# Função Wait Selenium não consegue capturar elemento, mas com o Thread.Sleep sim

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Olá, estou com um problema tem um tempo e não consigo descobrir o que é.

Estou usando o selenium em C# e ao tentar localizar um elemento em tela, me retorna um erro.

```
 OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException : element click intercepted: Element <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AbrirCampos('FornecedoresPromocoes', '0', '#divCampos', '#divLista')">...</button> is not clickable at point (164, 238). Other element would receive the click: <div class="mainnav__categoriy py-3">...</div>
```

meu código está assim

```
 public void ClicarBotaoNovaPromocao()
{  wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("#divAcaoBotoes > button"))).Click(); 
}
```

tentei assim também e também da erro.

```
public void ClicarBotaoNovaPromocao()
{
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("#divAcaoBotoes > button"))).Click();
}
```

A única forma que funciona é se colocar um Thread.Sleep. Seja de 1 Segundo ou 5 segundos, dessa forma funciona, porém não é boas práticas usar o Thread.Sleep. Teria alguma outra solução?

```
    public void ClicarBotaoNovaPromocao()
  {

     Thread.Sleep(5000);
      chromeDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#divAcaoBotoes > button")).Click();
  }
```